# System.BadImageFormatException on running ServiceStack AutoQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, ormlite-servicestack

The Project is running on asp.netcore 3.1.0. I encountered the exception System.BadImageFormatException  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost. I just can't get AutoQuery working.

the stack trace is below

```
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnStartupException(Exception ex) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 673
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.RunPostInitPlugin(Object instance) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 870
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.AfterPluginsLoaded(String specifiedContentType) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 901
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnAfterInit() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 792
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 296
   at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder app, AppHostBase appHost) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 281
   at Revopos.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DatabaseContext dbContext) in C:\repos\netcore\Revopos\Revopos.Api\Startup.cs:line 182
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

below is my AppHost codes

[image]

[image: code in Startup Configure]

Comment: Wont be possible to debug this issue without a stand-alone repro, if you can publish a project with this issue to GitHub & post the link here I can take a look.

Comment: I will try to repro it.  Previously I have issues to use a class inherited ServiceStack.Service and at the same time the same class was DI in asp.netcore as scoped. Is there any incompatibilities issues with asp.netcore DI ?